# redirect url is not working in box app

Tags: box-api

why my redirect url is not working when i mention it in box app?

Steps

```
1.created a new app
2.got the api key, client_id and client_secret 
3.gave my redirect url to be http://localhost:3000
4.click the app and add it to my box account it doesn't redirect to my local account,also
  tried with http://www.somesite.com and https://www.somesite.com
```

but it is not working can anyone please tell what is going wrong in creating the app

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could post the code you're using to generate the request and/or an HTTP trace of the request that's sent to Box.

Comment: i just created a simple app using the developers account. it doen't redirect after i click allow from box interface